# Configuration management for Linux / Hadoop Cluster

Tags: linux, hadoop, configuration

I have to setup a small size Hadoop cluster on Linux (Ubuntu) machines. For that I have to install JDK, python and some other linux utilities on all systems. After that I have to configure Hadoop for each system one by one. Is there any tool available so that I can install all these tools from a single system. For example if I have to install jdk on some system, that tool should install to that. I prefer the tool is web based .

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Ambari or Cloudera Manager are purposely built to accomplish these tasks for Hadoop

They also monitor the cluster, and provision extra services that communicate with it like Kafka, Hbase, Spark, etc

That only gets you so far, though, and you'll want to have something like Ansible to deploy custom configurations (AWX is a web UI for Ansible). Puppet & Chef are alternatives too